# Как построить массив PHP из двух таблиц sql?

Tags: php, mysql, массивы

Не получается построить многомерный массив. Есть две таблицы *MySQL*: `lost`, `history_lots`.

Из первой таблицы создается сам массив. А во второй таблице мы должны проверять, есть ли у нас действительно такой лот, и, если он есть, то находим в массиве *ID* и присваиваем ключу `my` значение `true`. Это самый конец массива. Сейчас, соответственно, в конце везде `"my":"false"`.

Мой код:

```
$rows = array();
$query = "SELECT * FROM cs_lots WHERE active_lot='1'";
$res2 = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT id_lot
          FROM cs_lots_history
          WHERE user_steamid='".$_SESSION['steamid']."'";
$result1 = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res2)) {
    $rows []= array(
        'id' => $row['id'],
        'inv_id' => $row['inv_id'],
        'inv_assets' => $row['inv_assets'],
        'name' => $row['inv_name'],
        'inv_image' => $row['inv_image'],
        'inv_rarity' => $row['inv_rarity'],
        'inv_color' => $row['inv_color'],
        'inv_type' => $row['inv_type'],
        'inv_price' => $row['inv_price'],
        'price_ticket' => $row['price_ticket'],
        'maxUsers' => $row['places'],
        'nowUsers' => $row['now_places'],
        'my' => false
      );
}
```

Сам вид массива:

```
LOTS = [{"id":"166","inv_id":"989","inv_assets":"3432669422","name":"Redline ","inv_image":"image","inv_rarity":"Field-Tested","inv_color":"d32ce6","inv_type":"1","inv_price":"2105.97","price_ticket":"14","maxUsers":"240","nowUsers":"1","my":false},  
{"id":"167","inv_id":"929","inv_assets":"3551634073","name":"Hyper Beast ","inv_image":"image","inv_rarity":"Battle-Scarred","inv_color":"eb4b4b","inv_type":"1","inv_price":"924.43","price_ticket":"8","maxUsers":"180","nowUsers":"0","my":false},  
{"id":"168","inv_id":"1104","inv_assets":"3313740799","name":"Asiimov ","inv_image":"image","inv_rarity":"Battle-Scarred","inv_color":"eb4b4b","inv_type":"1","inv_price":"1495.00","price_ticket":"13","maxUsers":"180","nowUsers":"19","my":false},  
{"id":"169","inv_id":"847","inv_assets":"3603670527","name":"Jaguar ","inv_image":"image","inv_rarity":"Battle-Scarred","inv_color":"eb4b4b","inv_type":"1","inv_price":"2711.65","price_ticket":"13","maxUsers":"320","nowUsers":"8","my":false},  
{"id":"170","inv_id":"1100","inv_assets":"3313741398","name":"Asiimov ","inv_image":"image","inv_rarity":"Field-Tested","inv_color":"eb4b4b","inv_type":"1","inv_price":"2756.70","price_ticket":"16","maxUsers":"260","nowUsers":"10","my":false},  
{"id":"171","inv_id":"899","inv_assets":"3551642235","name":"Atomic Alloy ","inv_image":"image","inv_rarity":"Factory New","inv_color":"d32ce6","inv_type":"1","inv_price":"862.50","price_ticket":"8","maxUsers":"180","nowUsers":"1","my":false}];
```

Каким образом я могу получить результат из запроса `$result1` и сравнить его с ключом *ID* в массиве?

Например, если `$result1_row['id_lot'] = $row['id']` - то тогда в конце тела массива пишем `my:true`.

Comment: тем не менее какой-то код вы написали за два часа, покажите его нам. может, и задача понятнее станет

Comment: Дополняйте ваш вопрос согласно [рекомендациям по ведению дискуссий на Stack Overflow](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/691/6), вместо публикации комментариев. Если у вас возник новый вопрос, задайте его отдельно, сославшись на этот для предоставления контекста.

Answer (score 1):

Получить нужные вам сведения можно одним двух-табличным запросом. Лучше всего воспользоваться `LEFT JOIN`. Если соответствующей записи в таблице `cs_lots_history` нет - будет возвращаться `NULL`, наличие которого можно проверить при помощи конструкции `IS NULL`. В зависимости от полученного результата столбцу my можно присваивать значение true или false.

```
SELECT
  l.id AS id,
  l.inv_id AS inv_id,
  l.inv_assets AS inv_assets,
  l.name AS name,
  l.inv_image AS inv_image,
  l.inv_rarity AS inv_rarity,
  l.inv_color AS inv_color,
  l.inv_type AS inv_type,
  l.inv_price AS inv_price,
  l.price_ticket AS price_ticket,
  l.places AS places,
  l.now_places AS now_places,
  IF(h.id_lot IS NULL, 0, 1) AS my
FROM
  cs_lots AS l
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT
     DISTINCT id_lot
  FROM
    cs_lots_history
  WHERE
    user_steamid = '".$_SESSION['steamid']."') AS h
ON
  h.id_lot = l.id
WHERE
  l.active_lot = '1'
```